# Right syntax to do an INSERT in PostgreSQL with multiple IF conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a quite large table of sporting events and I am cleaning up trying to arrange everything in smaller and cleaner tables. I am getting there, but I found an obstacle. This is the original table structure:

```
date  |  team_name  |  team_id  |  opposition  |  opposition_id  |  venue
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here is what I want to do with it. A part of what I will write now is pseudocode, because I am not very sure how can I express this in PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(date, home, away)
SELECT DISTINCT date, (...)
```

For the next two fields after date, I want to insert in the column `home` of the new table the values of the original column `team_id` **IF** the value in the original column `venue` is "home". If the value of `venue` is not "home", then in the new column `home` of the new table I will insert the values of the original `opposition_id`.

Can this be done easily? I found a question dealing with multiple IFs in MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265919/mysql-update-multiple-if-conditions), but I am not very sure about how would I adapt that method to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
insert  into NewTable
        (date, home)
select  date
,       case venue 
        when 'home' then team_id
        else opposition_id
        end
from    YourTable
```

Comment: Excellent! It took me a few tries to get my (much longer) real case working, but it's perfect now.